# Singly linked list for storing word and addresses in Java

Tags: java, search, linked-list

I have a problem in which I am required to create (1) a linked list of words and (2) for each word a separate linked list for storing that word's addresses (urls in this case as you can imagine it like a search engine: A keyword is identified/contained in specific urls).

```
public class SearchEngine {
WNode whead;


public void insert(String word, String url) {
    WNode wnode = new WNode(word);
    UNode unode = new UNode(url);
    if (whead == null) {

        whead = wnode;

        wnode.mid = unode;

    }
    else {
        WNode wtemp = whead;

        while (wtemp.next != null && !wtemp.word.equals(wnode.word)) {
            wtemp = wtemp.next;

        }


        if (wtemp.word.equals(wnode.word)) {

            UNode utemp = wtemp.mid;
            while (utemp.next != null) {
                utemp = utemp.next;
            }
            utemp.next = unode;
            wnode = null;
        }



        else {

           wtemp.next = wnode;

           wnode.mid = unode;
        }
    }
 }



public String toString() {
    WNode wordTemp = whead;

    String str = "";
    String str1 = "";
    while (wordTemp != null) {
       UNode urlTemp = wordTemp.mid;
       while (urlTemp != null) {
           str += urlTemp.url + " ";
           urlTemp = urlTemp.next;
       } 
       str1 += wordTemp.word + ": " + str + "\n";
       wordTemp = wordTemp.next;
    }
    return str1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   SearchEngine engine = new SearchEngine();
   engine.insert("A", "a.com");
   engine.insert("A", "b.com");
   engine.insert("B", "c.com");


   System.out.println(engine);
}
}

class WNode {
String word;
UNode mid;
WNode next;

WNode(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}
}

class UNode {
String url;
UNode next;

UNode(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

}
```

I want the output to be something like this:
Let's say I created a very first word node (wnode) "A", and it's first ever url "a.com" (in unode) by doing `engine.insert("A", "a.com)`, so `System.out.println(engine)` should give me the output:

```
A: a.com
```

Next, if I do `engine.insert("A", "b.com")` a new word node MUST NOT be linked to the linked list of word node(s) and now "b.com" should be linked into A's url's linked list. The output should be :

```
A: a.com b.com
```

However, when I try to do `engine.insert("B", "c.com")`, what I want is that a new word node should be LINKED (as there's only one word node (which is of A's)) to the linked list of word node(s) and now this word node's "mid" is attached to the local url node (unode) reference variable and the output SHOULD be :

```
A: a.com b.com

B: c.com
```

But when I run this, this is the output:

```
A: a.com b.com

B: a.com b.com c.com
```

What am I doing wrong here? I think my logic is alright. Is this because of the `toString()` method? I need some serious help. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation logic is alright, except for your `toString()` method. When you are finished with one `WNode`, you have to empty the string which holds the contents of the corresponding `UNode`.

```
public String toString() {
    WNode wordTemp = whead;

    String str1 = "";
    while (wordTemp != null) {
        String str = "";
        UNode urlTemp = wordTemp.mid;
        while (urlTemp != null) {
            str += urlTemp.url + " ";
            urlTemp = urlTemp.next;
        }
        str1 += wordTemp.word + ": " + str + "\n";
        wordTemp = wordTemp.next;
        str = ""; //empty the string here
    }
    return str1;
}
```

Take a look at the second last line, where I commented. That's what you have to insert to make it work correctly. Otherwise you will just be appending the content of all `UNode` over time.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 3):

You are not resetting `str` in your outer while loop, which causes it to carry over the urls to the next iteration. See the fixed `toString()` below:

```
public String toString() {
    WNode wordTemp = whead;

    String str1 = "";
    while (wordTemp != null) {
       String str = "";
       UNode urlTemp = wordTemp.mid;
       while (urlTemp != null) {
           str += urlTemp.url + " ";
           urlTemp = urlTemp.next;
       } 
       str1 += wordTemp.word + ": " + str + "\n";
       wordTemp = wordTemp.next;
    }
    return str1;
}
```